# How to plot a closed polygon with a spline in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, polygon, spline

I tried to create a spline around a polygon with gnuplot (see picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEEW7.png)). Unfortunately without success.
All "smooth " variants do not solve the problem, because most of them sort the x-values and "Bezier" is no spline. 
Are there any other ideas?
[Spline was created with LibreCalc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEEW7.png)

Answer (score 1):

The development version of gnuplot uses a general path-following spline in 3D plots. This comes close to what you ask for, but has the limitations that

- In order to trigger the path-following spline the points must not lie in a plane (the complicated third entry in the `using` spec below is just to move the points out of the xy plane).
- You won't get rounding at the join point for the start/end of the path
- This plot mode is not in a released gnuplot version
- It only applies to `splot`, not `splot`

Example

```
 unset key
 set view map
 splot 'spline.dat' using 1:2:($1==1?0:$0)  smooth cspline with lines lt 1, \
       '' using 1:2:($1==1?0:$0)  with points pt 7 lt 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

***18 months later***

Since I see that this question is still getting views, I am adding an updated answer.  The limitations mentioned in the first answer have now been removed. Gnuplot 5.5 (the development version) support a new smoothing option `smooth path` in both 2D and 3D plots.

Here is the documentation section:

```
gnuplot> help smooth path

 The `smooth path` option generates cubic splines to fit points in the order
 they are presented in the input data; i.e. they are not first sorted on x.
 This generates a smooth spline through a closed curve or along a trajectory
 that contains loops. This smoothing mode is supported for both 2D and 3D
 plot commands.  As always, a separate curve is created for each set
 of points in the input file, where a blank line separates the sets.
 Plotting `smooth path with filledcurves closed` will guarantee that each set
 of points creates a closed curve.  Plotting `smooth path with lines` will
 generate a closed curve if the first and last points in the set overlap,
 otherwise it will create an open-ended smooth path.
```

and here is part of [a from the online collection](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.5/smooth_path.html):

```
$LOOP << EOD
1.5 0.5
2.5 0.5
3   1.0
3.5 1.5
4.0 3.5
3.6 4.5
3.0 2.5
4   1.5
5   1.5
EOD

plot $CURVES using 1:2 with points pt 7 ps 2 lc "steelblue" title "original points", \
          '' using 1:2 smooth path with lines lt 3 title "smooth path with lines", \
     $LOOP using 1:2 with points pt 7 ps 2 lc "steelblue" notitle, \
        '' using 1:2 smooth path with lines lt 3 notitle
```

[image]